# MySQL re-order row priority field values and also make them sequential

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Name              |  Priority |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | Andy              | 1         |
| 2      | Bob               | 2         |
| 3      | David             | 8         |
| 4      | Edward            | 9         |
| 5      | CHARLES           | 15        |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to move `CHARLES` to between Bob and David by Priority value (**ignore** the alphabetical list, this is just to make the desired result obvious).

(Also note the Priority values may not be sequential)

To do this I need to change CHARLES' current `Priority` (15) to Bob's Priority+1, and update David and Edward's Priority to `Priority+1`.

I can **DO** this if I know two things, the id of CHARLES and the Priority value of the row he must be after (Bob):

```
UPDATE mytable SET Priority = 
IF(ID = :charles_id, :bob_priority + 1, 
IF(Priority >= :bob_priority, 
Priority + 1, Priority))
```

The **PROBLEM** or at least question is, how could I compress the resulting values to 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 1,2,3,9,10 - and do it in one shot?

Oracle has a "pseudo field" which is the index of the row, but I don't know of anything equivalent in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is fairly trivial...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS priorities;

CREATE TABLE priorities
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,Name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,Priority INT NOT NULL
,INDEX(priority)
);

INSERT INTO priorities VALUES
(101,'Andy',1),
(108,'Bob',2),
(113,'David',8),
(124,'Edward',9),
(155,'CHARLES',15);

UPDATE priorities a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.id,x.name, @i:=@i+1 priority FROM priorities x, (SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY id) b
    ON b.id = a.id 
   SET a.priority = b.priority;

SELECT * FROM priorities
+-----+---------+----------+
| ID  | Name    | Priority |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 101 | Andy    |        1 |
| 108 | Bob     |        2 |
| 113 | David   |        3 |
| 124 | Edward  |        4 |
| 155 | CHARLES |        5 |
+-----+---------+----------+
```